# Remove predefined views from Window -> Show View

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm struggling with Show View window, I've added a menu contribution:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        
        <menuContribution locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=blabla">
            <menu label="Window">
                <command
                    commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
                    style="pulldown">
                </command>              
            </menu>
```

and all my views are visible there under the categories I defined but my problem is that all predefined views are also shown there so I can add a 'console' or 'outline' view to my app which is not what I want. How can I prevent them from showing in this window? I've seen a solution using activities where each of unwanted views was filtered but doing this for each of tens of available views doesn't seem reasonable.'

Comment: Show view only filters on activities. The only other thing you can do is leave out the plug-ins that contribute the views. Or if you are not using any of the standard views maybe even a pure e4 RCP which will be much smaller and not have any additions.

Comment: @greg-449 Is there maybe a different but clean way to give users a possibility to control which views are opened?